# Seaborn Heatmap Subplot: How to assign data to each subgraph

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to generate a heatmap with 24 subgraphs, using seaborn. At the end I would like to get something like this:

[image]

I tried with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

d1 = pd.read_csv('upper_POPC.txt', sep="    ", decimal=".")
d2 = pd.read_csv('upper_SDPE.txt', sep="    ", decimal=".")
d3 = pd.read_csv('upper_SDPS.txt', sep="    ", decimal=".")
d4 = pd.read_csv('upper_SAPI.txt', sep="    ", decimal=".")
d5 = pd.read_csv('upper_CDL2.txt', sep="    ", decimal=".")
d6 = pd.read_csv('upper_CHOL.txt', sep="    ", decimal=".")

heatmap_d1 = pd.pivot_table(d1, values='Value(s)', index='  X', columns='Y')
heatmap_d2 = pd.pivot_table(d2, values='Value(s)', index='  X', columns='Y')
heatmap_d3 = pd.pivot_table(d3, values='Value(s)', index='  X', columns='Y')
heatmap_d4 = pd.pivot_table(d4, values='Value(s)', index='  X', columns='Y')
heatmap_d5 = pd.pivot_table(d5, values='Value(s)', index='  X', columns='Y')
heatmap_d6 = pd.pivot_table(d6, values='Value(s)', index='  X', columns='Y')

smooth_d1 = gaussian_filter(heatmap_d1, sigma=1)
smooth_d2 = gaussian_filter(heatmap_d2, sigma=1)
smooth_d3 = gaussian_filter(heatmap_d3, sigma=1)
smooth_d4 = gaussian_filter(heatmap_d4, sigma=1)
smooth_d5 = gaussian_filter(heatmap_d5, sigma=1)
smooth_d6 = gaussian_filter(heatmap_d6, sigma=1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=4, figsize=(12, 8), sharey=True)

    p1 = sns.heatmap(smooth_d1, cmap="coolwarm", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, ax=axes[0,0])
    p2 = sns.heatmap(smooth_d2, cmap="coolwarm", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, ax=axes[1,0])
    p3 = sns.heatmap(smooth_d3, cmap="coolwarm", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, ax=axes[2,0])
    p4 = sns.heatmap(smooth_d4, cmap="coolwarm", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, ax=axes[3,0])
    p5 = sns.heatmap(smooth_d5, cmap="coolwarm", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, ax=axes[4,0])
    p6 = sns.heatmap(smooth_d6, cmap="coolwarm", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, ax=axes[5,0])
```

Output: This code is not working but when I plot only one dataset it works. 
Possible problem: The problem is in assigning each subgraph to a dataset (p1, p2...)... I tried several options but I can't find the correct way. What is the best/clear way to assign data to subgraphs using seaborn heatmap?

NB: 
This code is to plot one part of my data. The aim is to plot p1 to p6 in one column. and for the rest of the columns/lines, I will add the data once I understand how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is it not working exactly? What do you get?

Comment: @busybear I am getting an empty plots